# Copy worksheet into different workbook replacing current data

Tags: excel, vba, copy, worksheet

I am hoping someone can help me.

I have two workbooks.
Wb1 = FAC Trial
Wb2 = ROMAN

There are numerous worksheets within both workbooks. What I would like to happen is that the data in Wb2, worksheet named Format is copied into Wb1 worksheet named Format.

The worksheet in Wb1 is already named and is to be updated on a daily basis from Wb2. The data in Wb1 worksheet Format would be overwritten each time.  I was looking that this would happen at the click of a Command Button.  Wb2 would not be open at the time of clicking the Command Button.

I have found some code but it creates a new worksheet each time the code is run and I am unsure of how to change it to suit my needs.

thank you in advance any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: please edit your question and post the code you were using so far. This will help us to help you.

Comment: The code I was using was

Answer (score 2):

You can easily record a piece of code to do this yourself, simply use 'Record Macro' on the Developer ribbon.

For now, below should do what you're after (remember to update the filepath for workbook 2).

I have just copied the "Format" worksheet from the ROMAN workbook, then deleted the existing "Format" worksheet and re-named the new one to "Format".

```
Sub wsCopy()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1Format As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("[ENTER FILE PATH]\ROMAN.xlsx")
    Set ws1Format = wb1.Sheets("Format")
    Set ws2Format = wb2.Sheets("Format")

    '' Copy the "Format" worksheet to wb1.
    ws2Format.Copy Before:=ws1Format
    wb2.Close

    '' Delete existing "Format" worksheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws1Format.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '' Rename new sheet to "Format".
    wb1.Sheets("Format (2)").Name = "Format"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on @Ituner before

```
Sub wsCopy()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1Format As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("[ENTER FILE PATH]\ROMAN.xlsx")
    Set ws1Format = wb1.Sheets("Format")
    Set ws2Format = wb2.Sheets("Format")

    '' Copy the cells of the "Format" worksheet.
    ws2Format.Cells.Copy 


    '' Paste cells to the sheet "Format".
    wb1.Sheets("Format").Paste
    wb2.Close false 'remove false if you want to be asked if the workbook shall be saved.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I was using was

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click ()

With Workbooks ("ROMAN.xls")
      .Sheets ("Format").Copy_
      Before:=Workbooks ("FAC Trial.xls").Sheets ("Format")

End With

End Sub

As is obvious I had to have both workbooks open but I just wanted it to copy the data onto the format worksheet without creating a new one

Comment: You could use the code @Iturner posted. He's right that if you would've used the macro recorder you could have got it by yourself too.
However, I will give you another answer based on his code.

Answer (score 0):

Sub ReplaceSheets(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, SheetName As String)

```
wb1.Sheets(SheetName).Cells.Clear
wb2.Sheets(SheetName).Cells.Copy wb1.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1")
```

End Sub