# Copy two worksheets into different workbook replacing current data

Tags: excel, vba

I modified code from [Copy worksheet into different workbook replacing current data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785480/copy-worksheet-into-different-workbook-replacing-current-data).

If I deselect range or I have selected different cell than A1, code falls into 1004 error.

```vb
Sub TG_update()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1Format As Worksheet, ws2Format As Worksheet, ws3Format As Worksheet, ws4Format As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("[add your path.xlsx]")
    Set ws1Format = wb1.Sheets("SheetA1")
    Set ws2Format = wb2.Sheets("SheetB1")
    Set ws3Format = wb1.Sheets("SheetA2")
    Set ws4Format = wb2.Sheets("SheetB2")

    '' Copy the cells of the "Format" worksheet.
    ws2Format.Cells.Copy

    '' Paste cells to the sheet "Format".
    wb1.Sheets("SheetA1").Paste
    
    ws4Format.Cells.Copy

    wb1.Sheets("SheetB1").Paste
    
    wb2.Close False 'remove false if you want to be asked if the workbook shall be saved.
    wb1.Sheets("Store").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Date successfully updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: `"..if I deselect range or I have selected differt cell then A1..."`. I am not clear on this: the code simply copies worksheets from one workbook to another. Where are you deselecting a range or a cell different to A1?

Comment: Im working whit it. Lets say, that I go to sheetA1 do some stuff and last edited cell is C5, so that means if I go to sheet  "Store" and run macro TG_update I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Instead of copying and pasting millions of blank cells this code copies the worksheet from the source and pastes it to the workbook with the code. If the action is successful the old sheet is deleted. The final report alerts about errors if sheets weren't found.

```
Sub TG_update()
    ' 016

    Dim Wb As Workbook                      ' ThisWorkbook
    Dim WbS As Workbook                     ' Source
    Dim Ffn As String                       ' Full FileName
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim TabName() As String
    Dim i As Integer                        ' TabName index
    Dim n As Integer                        ' tab counter

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' specify the workbook to be copied from: Full path and name
    Ffn = "F:\AWK PC\Drive E (Archive)\PVT Archive\Class 1\1-2018 (Jan 2020)\TXL 180719 Z Distance.xlsm"
    ' enumerate the sheet names in CSV format (sheets must exist in Wb)
    TabName = Split("SheetA1,SheetB1", ",")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set WbS = Workbooks.Open(Ffn)
    For i = 0 To UBound(TabName)
        On Error Resume Next                ' suppress error if worksheet isn't found
        WbS.Worksheets(TabName(i)).Copy After:=Wb.Worksheets(Wb.Worksheets.Count)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    WbS.Close SaveChanges:=False

    On Error GoTo 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(TabName)
        For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
            If InStr(Ws.Name, TabName(i) & " (") = 1 Then
                Wb.Worksheets(TabName(i)).Delete
                Ws.Name = TabName(i)
            End If
        Next Ws
    Next i

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    MsgBox n & " of " & i & " worksheets were successfully updated.", _
           vbInformation, "Action report"
End Sub
```

Creative names like Wb1, Wb2, Ws1, Ws2, SheetA1, SheetA2 represent the punishment imaginative programmers inflict on those who come after them to correct their hastily concocted code. Give your VBA project a better reputation by bestowing names on your two worksheets that permit their identification.

Comment: Im still getting report: 0 of 1 worksheets were successfully updated. So nothing happend. IMO I have flaw in `TabName = Split`  Shoul I fill here all sheets names in borkbosk, or just that I want to copy? Is there any order? Im little bit ocnfused.

Comment: And one thing more, If the action will success and the old sheet will be deleted. Will I lost bounds to deleted sheet in others  sheets? I cant lose them.

Comment: `TabName = Split("SheetA1,SheetB1", ",")` lists the sheets which exist at source and will be copied to `Wb` where they will have the same names. Formulas referring to values on that sheet will probably lose their connection. If this happens please try add `.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to the `With Application` statement at the top and `.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` to the one at the bottom. If that doesn't help post a sample of a formula that gets corrupted, same formula before and after the copying.